# Matrices in information theory.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Hi guys I have a question here which i'm trying to understand so this is regarding 5G polar codes btw

I have this matrix

$K$=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}

So would this be my generator matrix?

$K^{n+1}$=\begin{bmatrix}0&K^{n}\\K^{n}&K^{n}\end{bmatrix}

Also could anyone guide me in how I figure out the codewords for 4 bit code?

Any help would be massively appreciated thanks guys!

Sorry if the question is written poorly, this is my first question, thanks again.

Comment: Do you mean $K^{\otimes n+1}=\begin{bmatrix}0&K^{\otimes n}\\K^{\otimes n}&K^{\otimes n}\end{bmatrix}$ where $K^{\otimes n}$ is $n$ times the tensor product of $K$ with itself ?

Comment: I'm not sure, this is my generator matrix if that makes sense? @P.Quinton

Comment: What is the size of the matrix $K^n$ in this context?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that 
$$
K^{n+1} = \begin{bmatrix}0&K^{n}\\K^{n}&K^{n}\end{bmatrix}
$$
is supposed to be a recursive description of the generator matrices $K^n$.  Going off of [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_matrix), the codewords consist of all linear combinations of the rows of the generator matrix.  However, in your case the matrix $K$ is invertible.  Consequently, $K^n = K^{\otimes n}$ will be invertible for all $n$.  That is, the codewords for $K^n$ are all $1,0$-sequences of length $2^n$.